# Knockout js observable arrays and checkbox, checked bind fail

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out why the text entry field is not active when the checkbox changes?

```
<form data-bind="foreach: editables">
    <input type="checkbox" name="edit" data-bind=" checked: active" />
    <input type="text" name="edit" data-bind="value: name, disable: !active" />
    <br/>
</form>

var viewModel = function () {
   this.editables = ko.observableArray(
[{
    active: true,
    name: "mi"
}, {
    active: false,
    name: "yo"
}, {
    active: true,
    name: "cel"
}]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/legolito/2FAJN/2/

I hope that someone can helpme. (english isn't my native language, so i'm sorry if something is bad with my grammar )

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making the `active` property an `observable`?

http://jsfiddle.net/tzG3t/

```
var viewModel = function () {
    this.editables = ko.observableArray(
    [{
        active: ko.observable(true),
        name: "mi"
    }, {
        active: ko.observable(false),
        name: "yo"
    }, {
        active: ko.observable(true),
        name: "cel"
    }]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

That because you are not using `ko.observable` in `ko.observableArray`

See the [knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) on observableArrays

> **Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array, not the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

So make it observable and problem solved.
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2FAJN/4/